# Multiple tests running with RavenDB

Tags: c#, .net, testing, ravendb

I am working on WebAPI application using RavenDB.
I have a couple of XUnit tests which have kind of a similar outline:

```
var checkQuery = session.Query<Resource>().Where(x => x.AliasIds.Any(a => a == alias.Id));
PAssert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(() => checkQuery.Single());

var testString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
Controller.Post(testString);

var res = checkQuery.Single();
PAssert.IsTrue(() => res != null);
```

What happens is that when I have multiple tests run at the same time they fail at the line

```
var res = checkQuery.Single();
```

With exception:

> *Result Message:  System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains no elements*

What I have found:

- It works fine if I got first call to checkQuery.Single() commented.
- It works fine if I add Thread.Sleep(1000) before problematic line.

I tried to add

```
store.DatabaseCommands.DisableAllCaching();
store.Conventions.ShouldCacheRequest = _ => false;
```

but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `Controller.Post(testString)` is adding a new entry, you probably just have a stale index.  In the real world, some natural amount of time would pass between post and query.  In unit tests, you don't have that delay, so it's common to provide the following on your index:

```
.Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults())
```

This is not something you should do in production.  You can read more [in the documentation here](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/querying/stale-indexes).

Comment: Didn't check if it is an answer yet, but is there a way to set it up this way in store configuration somewhere?